# Adding MvvmCross to a Xamarin.iOS project hides Custom Control from Xamarin Designer Toolbox

Tags: ios, xamarin, storyboard, custom-controls, mvvmcross

I created a Xamarin.iOS project and added following Custom Control:

```
using Foundation;
using UIKit;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System;

[Register ("DesignerAwareLabel")]
public class DesignerAwareLabel : UITextField, IComponent {

    #region IComponent implementation

    public ISite Site { get; set; }
    public event EventHandler Disposed;

    #endregion

    public DesignerAwareLabel (IntPtr handle) : base (handle) { }

    public override void AwakeFromNib ()
    {

        Placeholder = "Foo";
        this.Layer.BorderWidth = 1;
    }
}
```

I added a storyboard and opened it in Xamarin Designer. After building the project, my Custom Control was shown up in the Toolbox.

But when I add MvvmCross via NuGet to my project and rebuild it - the Custom Control has gone from the Toolbox.

Removing the MvvmCross NuGet package makes it available again.

What am I doing wrong? I'd like to use both, MvvmCross-Package and the Custom Control within the storyboard.

Comment: As I figured out, my Custom Control will be removed from Designer when adding Cirrious.CrossCore.dll and Cirrious.CrossCore.Touch.dll

Comment: Additional info from iOSDesigner log file:

Jun  8 22:05:14  MonoTouchDesignServerUnified[3007]: [2015-06-08 22:05:14.9] WARN:   - Could not resolve dependency `Cirrious.CrossCore, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=e16445fd9b451819'